# Objectbox: ObjectBoxException 10101 remove failed

Tags: objectbox, flutter-objectbox, greenrobot-objectbox

I am getting the above error while removing multiple box data in transaction. I need to know what is the reason for that and what can be done to avoid this. Thanks very much for the help.

Stack trace is mentioned below.

> Non-fatal Exception: FlutterError 0  ???
> 0x0 ObjectBoxNativeError.throwMapped + 78 (helpers.dart:78) 1  ???
> 0x0 (null).throwLatestNativeError + 50 (helpers.dart:50) 2  ???
> 0x0 (null).checkObx + 17 (helpers.dart:17) 3  ???
> 0x0 Box.removeMany. + 329 (box.dart:329) 4  ???
> 0x0 (null).executeWithIdArray + 188 (helpers.dart:188) 5  ???
> 0x0 Box.removeMany + 328 (box.dart:328) 6  ???
> 0x0 BoxTransaction.deleteRouteDataonRouteRestoreFailure. + 135
> (transaction.dart:135) 7  ???                            0x0
> Store.runInTransaction. + 468 (store.dart:468) 8  ???
> 0x0 Store._runInTransaction + 643 (store.dart:643) 9  ???
> 0x0 Store.runInTransaction + 468 (store.dart:468) 10 ???
> 0x0 BoxTransaction.deleteRouteDataonRouteRestoreFailure + 134
> (transaction.dart:134) 11 ???                            0x0
> DeleteRouteData.deleteDataPastWindow + 189 (route_delete.dart:189) 12
> ???                            0x0
> SplashScreenPresenter._deleteDataPastWindow + 322
> (splash_screen_presenter.dart:322) 13 ???
> 0x0 SplashScreenPresenter.handleAppStart + 81
> (splash_screen_presenter.dart:81)

Reproducible code

```
store.runInTransaction(TxMode.write, () {

    store.box<Type1>.removeMany(ids1);
    store.box<Type2>.removeMany(ids2);
    .... 10 more tables


});
```

Comment: To help you we would need the error message. The stack trace above only includes ???.

Comment: This is the error message `ObjectBoxException 10101 remove failed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error code (10101) indicates that the database is full.

As a temporary workaround, you can try to re-write your code to not wrap the remove calls in a transaction (or wrap less remove calls in the transaction). This will require less storage space, so it may succeed with the remaining space in the database.

```
store.box<Type1>.removeMany(ids1);
store.box<Type2>.removeMany(ids2);
.... 10 more tables
```

Comment: Thanks for describing the error code. I will wrap less remove calls. So what does database is full means ? We cannot add further data to any of the boxes ? When will it get full ?

Comment: There is a default limit of 1 Gigabyte on the database file size to prevent it from accidentally growing indefinitely. There is a maxDBSizeInKB argument when creating a Store on how to change it, see https://pub.dev/documentation/objectbox/latest/objectbox/Store/Store.html.